# Animate a face rig based on data from an external source

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, 3d-manipulator

I would like to know if it's possible to use Blender to make a 3D animation of a person that simulates the spoken dynamic information working with the API of DialogFlow, for an intelligent robot?

I want to animate a face  with facial expressions that will animate the information that the other person want to listen, like a real conversation between two people, like the head of the robot. But I don't have any idea if blender can do that and how.

Comment: Can you turn that on its head and just say you want to animate a mouth rig based on data from an external source? If so, what form does the data or the interaction with the data from DialogFlow take? You have added the tag "blender-render" this is the old, soon to be retired rendering engine, if that is not a requirement I suggest you remove it.

Comment: I'm new using blender and this community, but as you said I want to animate a face instead of a mouth with facial expressions that will animate the information that I the other person want to listen, like a real conversation between to people, but it will be in a monitor like the head of the robot. But I don't have any idea if blender can do that and how.

Comment: If you google "blender lip sync" and "blender drivers" you should find that the basic idea is plausible. I could not find anything specific to DialogFlow.